# AngularJS: how to check for username availability?

Tags: angularjs

I have input textbox to enter username. I want to check for username availability and display error/success message like username validation in below code. What is the best possible way to do this?

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8">
  <p>User Name*:</p>
  <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" ng-model="uname" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 800 }" ng-change="check(uname)" required />
  <span style="color:red" ng-show="form.uname.$dirty && form.uname.$invalid">
  <span ng-show="form.uname.$error.required">User Name is Required</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-change directive and call a function which will call server and verify whether username exists or not and depending on that display error/success to user.

I presume that is what is already been done and I dont see any other alternative apart from a server call.

Answer (score 1):

Look like you missing form element

```
 <form name="myForm">
        <label>
            User name:
            <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" required>
            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.userName.$error.required">
                Required!
            </span>
        </label>
 </form>
```